# JSONModel: проблема с описанием модели

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Добрый день: Помогите разобраться с JSONModel. 
Ссылка на скриншоты https://yadi.sk/d/ClyoCyVMkoToC
Пришлось сделать все скрины в одну папку, т.к. не могу добавить больше одной ссылки
Суть проблемы:

Проект принимает JSON с сайта. NSlog выглядит так ( скрин 1)

Есть модель CatalogModel (скрин 2)

Код который обрабатывает (скрин 3)

При запуске получаю ошибку ( скрин 4 и скрин 5)

Чистка проекта не помогает.

Если убираю из модели ListModel, то всё отлично работает.

Как я понимаю, то я не правильно описываю модель, но этот пример описания я взял со страницы проекта на  гитхабе.

Comment: судя по пятому скрину проблема в том, что в классах CatalogModel и NTCatalogController существуют duplicate symbols. Проверьте, что вы не импортируете `.m`, и давайте смотреть что там в этих классах.

Comment: Нет, .m точно не импортируется. Проблема появляется, когда в CatalogModel.h я добавляю ListModel

Comment: как я уже написал, надо видеть, что происходит в этих классах.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/lBFjUkd0koyVw Тут 4 файлика используемых.

Comment: пока ничего подозрительного. в NTCatalogControllerDetail.h импортируется CatalogModel?

Comment: Нет, не импортируется.
Меня всё равно сильно смущает то, что ошибка появляется при  добавлении ListModel. Без неё ошибки нет.

Comment: я так понимаю вы сильно секрета из своего проекта не делаете. я бы предложил выложить весь код где то, на посмотреть

Comment: Секрета не делаю, просто отложил этот момент после публикации вопроса и стал двигаться дальше, чтобы время не терять. Я сделаю по другому, я создам новый проект, и туда добавлю все эти махинации, чтобы основной проект не трогать каждый раз. Думаю, что так будет разумнее. Минут через 15 - 20  выложу.

Comment: Готово. Эффект такой же.  
https://yadi.sk/d/yAUcCExMkpkKc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас `@implementation ListModel` находится в хэдере, по этому когда вы его импортируете во вью контроллере получается, что ListModel имеет две разных имплементации, что с точки зрения компилятора duplicate symbols (что вы и видите в ошибке).

Что с этим делать?

- лучше всего не складыывать два класса в один файл - ListModel отдельно, CatalogModel отдельно.
- Если такой вариант не устраивает, просто перенести @implementation в .m

Еще совет: переименовать протокол `ListModel` в `ListModelDelegate`, чтобы избежать путаницы.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать вечером.

Comment: Max, громадное Вам спасибо. Вы спасли мои нервы))

Comment: галочку не забудьте :)